# Method overloading with floating types

Tags: java

What will be the output of following code?The output is coming to be `1.0` but this means it is giving preference to `double` parameters instead of floating parameter. Please someone explain what is the mechanism behind this output.

```
class X
    {

     int method(int i)
    {

        return i *= i;
    }
}

class Y extends X
{
    double method(double d)
    {
        return d /= d;    
    }
}
class Z extends Y
{
    float method(float f)
    {
        return f += f;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Z z = new Z();

        System.out.println(z.method(21.12));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

`21.12` is a `double` literal, which is why `double method(double d)` is chosen. For `float` literals you have to use `21.12f` or `21.12F`. `z.method(21.12f)` would invoke `float method(float f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because by default the decimal number type is `double` in java so at this point

```
 System.out.println(z.method(21.12));
```

java gonna consider 21.12 values is a `double` not `float` hence java look-up table try to find the best match with `double` value

The float literals as marked with either `f`  or `F` so to call function with floating values do this

```
 System.out.println(z.method(21.12f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your literal 21.12 is treated as a double by the runtime. You could try "21.12F" to explicitly make it into a float.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a floating point literal like 21.12 is interpreted as **double** by the compiler (you would need to use 21.12f to make it a **float**).

So, at compile time, the compiler searches for that method that matches the most closest; in that case, the double-taking one from your base class.