# Overloaded function throws an error for float arguments

Tags: java, overloading

This is my Java program code. I overloaded the `add` function for the data types `int` and `float`, but the call `add(2.3, 2.4)` throws an error, instead of calling `add(float, float)`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This calls add(int, int) as expected
        System.out.println(add(2,4));

        // This call throws an error
        System.out.println(add(2.3,3.4));

    }

    public static int add(int a, int b){
        return (a + b);
    }

    public static float add(float a, float b){
        return (a + b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, when you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: change method call to System.out.println(add(2.3f,3.4f));

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069722/method-overloading-with-floating-types/40069743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the overloaded methods correctly!

What you got wrong is the way you call the methods. You are calling `add(2.3,3.4)`. `2.3` and `3.4` are all `double`s. That's why they can't be directly put into a method that accepts floats.

"What? Why are they doubles?" you might ask.

By default, all number literals without a `.` or `e` are considered to be `int`s. And all number literals that has either or both a `.` or `e` are considered to be `double`s.

To create a float literal, add `f` to the end of the numbers. i.e. these are all floats:

```
1f
1000f
1.1f
-9f
1e99f
```

So you should call your method like this

```
add(2.3f,3.4f)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are `add` methods for `int` and `float`, while literal `2.3` has type `double`. There two ways to fix this:

1. Use `float` literals, i.e. `2.3f` and `3.4f` (notice the `f` suffix).
2. Define `add` method for `double`s.